# Compiling Java code on the command line in Mac OS X

Tags: java, macos, compiler-construction, scripting

Really basic question I'm sure for some of you Java heads out there.

I have a list of java files and jars that are required.

On windows to build I have this batch file

```
javac -cp .;opencsv-1.8.jar;mysql-connector.jar -source 1.4 -target 1.4 *.java
jar cvf cup.jar *.class
del *.class
```

If I want to do the same thing on mac how would a write a shell script to do the same?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Basically the same thing, except

1. The path separator is ':' instead of ';'
2. I believe the command to delete is called 'rm'

Also, I'd put a shabang at the start.

So:

```
#!/bin/sh
javac -cp .:opencsv-1.8.jar:mysql-connector.jar -source 1.4 -target 1.4 *.java
jar cvf cup.jar *.class
rm *.class
```

Comment: Yup, forgot the bang part of the shabang.

Comment: Thanks, the ':' in the path separator was the one catching me out.